# SQL Server 2005 Group by alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I have

```
 select CustID,

case permission
When 'read' then 'X'
end as 'Read',

case permission
when 'write' then 'X'
end as 'Write',

case permission
when 'own' then 'X'
end as 'Own',

case permission
when ‘destroy’ then ‘X’
end as ‘Destroy’

from rights

group by custID, permission
```

I just want one line for each custID. Instead I get:

```
CustID    |  Read | Write |  Own | Destroy

208345482     X     NULL    NULL   NULL| 
208345482    NULL   NULL     X     NULL|
208345482    NULL   NULL    NULL      X|
208345482    NULL    X      NUL    NULL|
8093657522   NULL   NULL    NULL     X|
8093657522   NULL   NULL     X    NULL|
```

I have tried to group by aliased subqueries to no avail. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use an alias in `GROUP BY` because it is parsed before the alias is applied. The only place you can use the alias is in the `ORDER BY` clause, since it is the only clause parsed after `SELECT` where the aliases are defined.

Typical workarounds are either repeating the expression in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT x = CASE ... END, SUM(something)
  FROM dbo.somewhere
  GROUP BY CASE ... END;
```

Or using a CTE:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT x = CASE ... END, something
    FROM dbo.somewhere
)
SELECT x, SUM(something)
  FROM src
  GROUP BY x;
```

Or using a subquery:

```
SELECT x, SUM(something)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT x = CASE ... END, something
      FROM dbo.somewhere
  ) AS src
  GROUP BY x;
```

These should all optimize similarly but you should test your specific scenario to be sure.

In your case you can write this as follows:

```
SELECT CustID,
  [Read]    = MAX(CASE permission WHEN 'read'    THEN 'X' END),
  [Write]   = MAX(CASE permission WHEN 'write'   THEN 'X' END),
  [Own]     = MAX(CASE permission WHEN 'own'     THEN 'X' END),
  [Destroy] = MAX(CASE permission WHEN 'destroy' THEN 'X' END)
FROM dbo.rights
GROUP BY custID;
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT CustID,
  MAX([Read]), MAX([Write]), MAX([Own]), MAX([Destroy])
FROM
(
  SELECT CustID,
   [Read]    = CASE permission WHEN 'read'    THEN 'X' END,
   [Write]   = CASE permission WHEN 'write'   THEN 'X' END,
   [Own]     = CASE permission WHEN 'own'     THEN 'X' END,
   [Destroy] = CASE permission WHEN 'destroy' THEN 'X' END
  FROM dbo.rights
) AS src
GROUP BY custID;
```

Please don't use single quotes to delimit a column or table `'alias'`. Not only is the syntax deprecated but it also makes the entity look like a string literal. If it must be escaped (e.g. if you choose bad column names), use `[square brackets]`.

Comment: "You can't use an alias in GROUP BY because it is parsed before the alias is applied." But why it is parsed before the alias is applied?

Comment: @anario I don't know if I can really tell you why, except that's the way SQL Server works. (I believe MySQL is a little looser in this regard, but most of the real platforms should adhere more closely to the standard.) Some more details on [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19762/why-is-the-select-clause-listed-first/) and [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in/) over on dba.se.

Comment: Useful links, I am satisfied now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) table operator to do so in one query directly instead of these `CASE` expressions.

It will do the further step that you are looking for, which is the grouping of records after spreading them using the `CASE` expression. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  CustId, 
  read, 
  write, 
  own, 
  Destroy
FROM
( 
   SELECT custid, permission, x
   FROM tablename
) AS t
PIVOT
(
   MAX(x)
   FOR permission IN('read', 
                     'write', 
                     'own', 
                     'Destroy')
) AS p;
```

In your query, if the `x` is a string literal not an identifier, then you can select it normally as a string literal with an alias in the anchor query `SELECT custid, permission, 'x' AS x FROM tablename` then the query above should work fine.